# 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed-- This comes up whenever I am trying to create dummy variables for multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe

```
pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(z1[col]) for col in z1], axis=1, keys=z1.columns)
```

whenever I type the code it shows the error but not while I choose a single column to create a variable.

I have tried the following codes but none seems to work:

```
dum=pd.get_dummies(z1[['2','5','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','21','22','23','24','25','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','35','39','40','41','42','53','55','58','60','63','64','65','78','79']])
dum=pd.get_dummies(z1,columns=['2','5','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','21','22','23','24','25','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','35','39','40','41','42','53','55','58','60','63','64','65','78','79'], drop_first = True)
z1=pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(z1[col]) for col in z1], axis=1, keys=z1.columns)
```

I want to find the dummy variable for more than One column because creating a single dummy variable at a time for 81 columns is not really an option and is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a list comprehension, you can put the columns of your df directly inside the `pd.get_dummies`. Here is what it could look like :

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'var1':['a', 'a', 'b'], 'var2':['u', 'u', 'c'] })
pd.get_dummies(df[['var1', 'var2']])
```

Output

```
var1_a  var1_b  var2_c  var2_u
0   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   0   1
2   0   1   1   0
```

---

If you also have non categorical columns you could separate the different columns and us `pd.concat` to regroup them :

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'var1_cat':['a', 'a', 'b'], 'var2_cat':['u', 'u', 'c'], 'var3' : [0, 12, 19] })

not_categorical = df['var3']
categorical = df[['var1_cat', 'var2_cat']]

pd.concat([not_categorical] + [pd.get_dummies(categorical)], axis = 1)
```

Output :

```
var3    var1_cat_a  var1_cat_b  var2_cat_c  var2_cat_u
0   0   1   0   0   1
1   12  1   0   0   1
2   19  0   1   1   0
```